# Accessing from an Abstract Class

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Password  {
private String password;
private final static String ENCRYPTION_METHOD;

static  {
ENCRYPTION_METHOD = "CLEAR TEXT";
    }

public Password(String password)    {
    password = password;

}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public boolean matches (String aString) {
    if (aString.equals(password))   {
        return true;    }

        else    {
            return false;   }
        }

public String toString()    {
    return password;
}

public static String getEncryptionMethod()  {
    return ENCRYPTION_METHOD;
}

abstract String decrypt();
```

### }

```
  public class EncryptedPassword extends Password   {
private final static String ENCRYPTION_METHOD;

static  {
ENCRYPTION_METHOD = "PERMUTATION";
    }

public EncryptedPassword(String password)   {
    super(password);
}


public boolean matches (String aString) {
    if  (aString.equals("True"))    {
            return true;    }

            else    {
            return false;   }
                }

public String toString()    {
    return "Password: " + super.toString();
}


public String decrypt() {

    return password;
}

public static String getEncryptionMethod()  {
    return ENCRYPTION_METHOD;
}
```

}

Hi, i was wondering if you guys knew how I return my password on my EncryptedPassword class, but still by keeping it concrete and keeping my Password class Abstract. Is there any basic way of doing it. Also, sorry for the terrible formatting..

Comment: more specifically the    public String decrypt(){                  return password;            }

Answer (score 2):

You can change your method to:

```
public String decrypt() {
    return getPassword();
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the access modifier of the `password` field from `private` to `protected`.

Comment: well actually that method worked, and i want to keep it private for reasons, but it worked, so thank you very much!